# Given two points$ P_{1}(0, 0, 0)$ and $P_{2}(2, 2, 0)$ what is the plane equation equidistant from $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Tags: vectors, 3d

I have given two points $P_{1}(0, 0, 0)$ and $P_{2}(2, 2, 0)$ what is the plane equation equidistant from $P_1$ and $P_2$?

How can I find this?

Comment: Explain "following."

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Consider a plane through the midpoint, perpendicular to the segment $P_1P_2$.

Comment: If A(x1, y1, z1) and B(X2., y2, z2) are two points, then vector v=⟨x2−x1,y2−y1,z2−z1⟩ is normal to the desired plane. Right?

Comment: Furthermore, the midpoint of the line segment between A and B must lie in this plane. The midpoint is the point $$c=(\frac{x1+x2}{2} ,\frac{y1+y2}{2}, \frac{z1+z2}{2})$$

Comment: You could also simply put $(x,y, z)$ as being equidistant from the two points in the distance formula, that will render a plane locus as well

Comment: Answering these questions in the comments is all well and good, but in the future, you should put those answers in your original post. This improves the question and forestalls potential down-votes and close-votes. Moreover, comments are not considered part of the permanent record of the question and can be deleted without warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by the distance formula, $$(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-0)^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2$$
Which gives $x+y=2$.

Alternatively,
$(2-0,2-0,0-0)$ is direction ratio for the normal to the plane.The midpoint $M(1,1,0)$ must lie on the plane. Let $P(x, y, z)$ be any other point on the plane. The the direction ratio of $PM(x-1, y-1, z-0)$ is perpendicular to above mentioned normal. Take their dot product and put it zero$$(2,2,0)•(x-1, y-1, z) =0$$ giving $$2(x-1)+2(y-1)=0$$which is $$x+y=2$$

Answer (score 1):

If point $P$ is equidistance from $P_1$ and $P_2$ then this can expressed as follows:

$ (P - P_1) \cdot (P - P_1) = (P - P_2) \cdot (P - P_2) $

Expanding and simplifying,

$ P \cdot (P_2 - P_1) = \dfrac{1}{2} (P_2 \cdot P_2 - P_1 \cdot P_1 ) $

The right side can also be written as

$ \dfrac{1}{2} (P_2 - P_1) \cdot (P_2 + P_1) $

Putting it all together

$ P \cdot (P_2 - P_1) = \dfrac{1}{2} (P_2 - P_1) \cdot (P_2 + P_1) $

Which can re-written as

$ \left(P - \dfrac{1}{2} (P_1 + P_2) \right) \cdot (P_2 - P_1) = 0 $

And this is an equation of a plane whose normal vector is $(P_2 - P_1)$ and which passes through the point $\dfrac{1}{2} (P_1 + P_2) $.